# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag error, when it wrapped in a closing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
    return (
      <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        {Object.keys(fields).map(key => (
          <FormControl key={key} className={classes.formControl}>
            <TextField className={classes.textField} value={fields[key].type} />
            <IconButton
              aria-label={`Remove ${fields[key].type} field`}
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={() => deleteField(value, key, onChange)}
            >
              <ClearIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </FormControl>
          <div></div>
        ))}
      </form>
  );
```

Anything entered after the FormControl gives me this error, be it this example div or anything more complex. I can render anything inside the FormControl tags, but the moment it's moved out or anything else outside of them gets this error.

Comment: You have an extra `<div></div>` after your `FormControl` that doesn't do anything besides throw and error. Remove it

Comment: What is `<div></div>` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `<div></div>` segment after the `<FormControl />` is there for a reason, you will need to wrap the return with [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax). This is used to group the elements within the `Array.map()` callback

```
{Object.keys(fields).map(key => (
  <>
    <FormControl key={key} className={classes.formControl}>
      <TextField className={classes.textField} value={fields[key].type} />
      <IconButton
          aria-label={`Remove ${fields[key].type} field`}
          className={classes.button}
          onClick={() => deleteField(value, key, onChange)}
        >
        <ClearIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </FormControl>
    <div></div>
  </>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove `<div></div>` from after `<FormControl />`. And your code will work perfectly fine.

Comment: that div is just a placeholder. I have other code, but it's too long to paste here. It just represents what throws an error.

Comment: Well than wrap all the map into a ```Fragment``` like @wentjun said ```<> your code here </>```, and you can let that div where it is right now.